# Images for buttons in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Do I have to create (or download) images for iPhone UIButton's? 
I want a standard button with the iPhone look, but right now, all I can choose between are

- Rounded Rect
- Detail Disclosure
- Info Light
- Info Dark
- Add Contact

NOTE: I believe it was possible to download some image library from Apple before with standard buttons and so on.

Comment: UIButtonTypeRoundRect is Default style of iPhone UIButton. What type of default button you want ? Can you attache sample image ?

Comment: I was think about something like in the upper left corner..

http://teehanlax.com.s3.amazonaws.com/roger/wp-content/uploads/iphone_retina_elements1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder (or infact even if you are not!), the button types under 'type' should give you the default button types to get the Apple look. Adding your own images would be unconventional.

Comment: I was think about something like in the upper left corner..

http://teehanlax.com.s3.amazonaws.com/roger/wp-content/uploads/iphone_retina_elements1.jpg

Comment: Is this not a regular rounded button? (with the colour set to Green?)

Comment: No it has some gradient, a glass effect and some border around it. If you have an Iphone yourself, please go to Latest Calls tabs and press Clear List. Then you will see the buttons im talking about.

Comment: Do you mean the buttons that appear when the screen pops up to ensure you want to clear the list? (known as an UIActionSheet in cocoa-touch). If so these buttons are for those screens only. A regular button should be used elsewhere.

Comment: Allright, still I find the original button really booring, haven't seen it in any iphone app either. I guess I'll have to create my own button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Ray Wenderlichs tutorials. He has a long explanation of making buttons look awesome with core graphics. Best for reusability.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. You only have to declare the botton like a Round Rect one and this is all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image you want but you have to use a custom button type like :

```
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(anAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given image. You need to make image like that and need to use button type as custom.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customImageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can also define image from Interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can download icons as PNG or other files and set it to Button's Image..They maybe free or charga